# Training Pipeline fails after uploading model artifacts to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Here's a snippet of my training code:

```
param_grid = {
"max_tokens" : [100],
"max_len" : [10],
"dropout" : [0.1],
}
gs_model = GridSearchCV(KerasClassifier(build_model), param_grid, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
gs_model.fit(x_train, y_train, verbose = 1)
best_params = gs_model.best_params_
optimized_model = build_model(max_tokens = best_params["max_tokens"], max_len = best_params["max_len"], dropout = best_params["dropout"])
optimized_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 3, validation_split = 0.2, callbacks = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, verbose = 1))
model_name = "/tmp/custom-model-test"
optimized_model.save(model_name)
print('saved model to ', model_name)
upload_from_directory(model_name, "[redacted Bucket name]", "custom-model-test")
try: 
    upload_blob("[redacted Bucket name]", "goback-custom-train/requirements.txt", "custom-model-test/requirements.txt")
except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    print('Upload failed')
```

Which succeeds in uploading to Google Cloud Storage. It makes use of `model.save` from Keras, and saves the created directory to my Bucket, along with a `requirements.txt` file inside it. To be clear, once the code block above is ran, a directory `custom-model-test/` is created in `gs://[redacted Bucket name]` with contents `requirements.txt` and `tmp/`. Inside `tmp/` is `keras-metadata.pb`, `saved_model.pb`, and `variables/`.

I run this container in the following codeblock in my Kubeflow Pipeline:

```
training_job_run_op = gcc_aip.CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp(
    project = project,
    display_name = display_name,
    container_uri=training_container_uri,
    model_serving_container_image_uri=model_serving_container_image_uri,
    model_serving_container_predict_route = model_serving_container_predict_route,
    model_serving_container_health_route = model_serving_container_health_route,
    model_serving_container_ports = [8080],
    service_account = "[redacted service account]",
    machine_type = "n1-highmem-2",
    accelerator_type ="NVIDIA_TESLA_V100",
    staging_bucket = BUCKET_NAME)
```

For some reason, after training and saving the model artifacts (the logs for the model training says it completed successfully) the pipeline fails with logs saying:

```
" File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/training_jobs.py", line 905, in _raise_failure "
" raise RuntimeError("Training failed with:\n%s" % self._gca_resource.error) "
"RuntimeError: Training failed with: "
"code: 5
"message: "There are no files under \"gs://[redacted Bucket name]/aiplatform-custom-training-2022-04-21-14:04:46.151/model\" to copy."
"
```

What's going on here? What's the fix?

Comment: You might be having issues because you are redirecting you bucket to another bucket that is in another level or that the bucket isn't created.